# Table HeaderView iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a UITableView that needs to have something inserted at the top in some cases (not always).

The code (if it were to be a NORMAL) cell would be as follows

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,98,100)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;
//sets cell text
cell.textLabel.text = @"Number";
```

but I was told on here that it would be easier to implement a headerView than to change the indexPath each time.

So my question is how would I implement this? Would I use `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` or would I use `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`? Keep in mind, I have an image to place into the cell (headerView).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

`titleForHeaderInSection:` only sets the header as text, where as `viewForHeaderInSection:` will allow you to add a view, `UIImageView`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so it can be returned from

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

This is what you should do since it allows full customization of the header image.

If you instead use

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

then the **only** thing you have control over is the `NSString` that you return. You cannot add a background, change the font color, etc. Since you have an image, use the former method.